# Guiro part notation using cross notes

Tags: notation, sheet-music, percussion, latin-jazz

Here's a picture of a Guiro part in drum notation:

[image: score of guiro rhythm]

In a Guiro part, what does it mean when there are cross notes? I've seen other Guiro parts elsewhere that use the same line placement but with normal notes. So why cross notes here? Or what sound or playing technique is indicated with cross notes?

Comment: Could they be ghost notes? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_note#Percussion

Comment: @YourUncleBob - those crosses in Wiki are actually hi-hat notes, the snare notes being on 2nd space down, and never using crosses for ghost notes. Playing ghost notes on guiro - hardly worth having it at all..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are plenty of different note heads available in notation programs. Except of the drum-set and especially when all other percussion instruments have their own staff the selection and definition doesn’t matter and doesn’t mean anything. The different shapes of the note heads are only important for the composer and the conductor of the ensemble to identify the different instruments in the full score.

Comment: Having the option of blobs or crosses means two instruments can be shown on the same line/space. Of course that makes a problem when both play together...

Answer (score 2):

Don't think it makes much difference. It's actually where I prefer the snare to be - leaving the spaces for three toms and a kick drum. But more often, the 'x' is used for cymbals and hi-hat, even though the more important part is the stem and any tails indicating quavers/semis, etc.